# Getting Term Frequencies For Query

Tags: lucene

In Lucene, a query can be composed of many sub-queries. (such as TermQuery objects)

I'd like a way to iterate over the documents returned by a search, and for each document, to then iterate over the sub-queries.

For each sub-query, I'd like to get the number of times it matched. (I'm also interested in the fieldNorm, etc.)

I can get access to that data by using indexSearcher.explain, but that feels quite hacky because I would then need to parse the "description" member of each nested Explanation object to try and find the term frequency, etc. (also, calling "explain" is very slow, so I'm hoping for a faster approach)

The context here is that I'd like to experiment with re-ranking Lucene's top N search results, and to do that it's obviously helpful to extract as many "features" as possible about the matches.

Via looking at the source code for classes like TermQuery, the following appears to be a basic approach:

```
// For each document... (scoreDoc.doc is an integer)

Weight weight = weightCache.get(query);

if (weight == null)
{
    weight = query.createWeight(indexSearcher, true);
    weightCache.put(query, weight);
}

IndexReaderContext context = indexReader.getContext();
List<LeafReaderContext> leafContexts = context.leaves();
int n = ReaderUtil.subIndex(scoreDoc.doc, leafContexts);
LeafReaderContext leafReaderContext = leafContexts.get(n);
Scorer scorer = weight.scorer(leafReaderContext);
int deBasedDoc = scoreDoc.doc - leafReaderContext.docBase;
int thisDoc = scorer.iterator().advance(deBasedDoc);

float freq = 0;
if (thisDoc == deBasedDoc)
{
    freq = scorer.freq();
}
```

The 'weightCache' is of type Map and is useful so that you don't have to re-create the Weight object for every document you process. (otherwise, the code runs about 10x slower)

Is this approximately what I should be doing?  Are there any obvious ways to make this run faster? (it takes approx 2 ms for 280 documents, as compared to about 1 ms to perform the query itself)

Another challenge with this approach is that it requires code to navigate through your Query object to try and find the sub-queries. For example, if it's a BooleanQuery, you call query.clauses() and recurse on them to look for all leaf TermQuery objects, etc. Not sure if there is a more elegant / less brittle way to do that.

Comment: So, you are trying to modify the scores?  Implementing that in a [Similarity](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/Similarity.html) would certainly seem to be the right approach, instead of attempting to rescore after the fact.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful... maybe we'll try that approach as well. It certainly would be faster...